# How to implement Panning in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, geometry

I am trying to implement the panning. I've a subScene with perspective camera and a Box inside it. I am able to pan the box relative to the camera (So camera is fixed and the box moves left right-left-top-down). How can I achieve panning by not moving the box relative to the camera. Is there any way to move the camera inside the subScene(Usually its position is fixed).

The problem in my current approach is that when I pan the box to left, its right face is revealed more because of the perspective. It seems like the box rotates a little bit on pan. I want to remove this slight rotation effect on panning for which I need to pan the box and camera simultaneously in same direction (without any relative movement between them). But I am not able to figure out how to move the camera as the camera position is fixed with respect to the subScene.

Thanks.

Comment: The camera can be moved around the scene.  Here is a sample: [rotating perspective camera around an object in javaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763551/rotating-perspective-camera-around-an-object-in-javafx).  Perhaps you can adapt some of the principles to implement your required panning logic.

Comment: Actually, My requirement is not to move the object relative to the camera or the camera relative to the object.