# Change point of rotation of an image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Hi I am working with an automotive UI project using JavaFX. I am trying to rotate a speed needle image. The image is rotating from its center. I need to rotate it by from its end.How to change the point of rotation like a pivot point or something.?Here is my code

```
private void rotateNeedle(){
    rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(3), speedNeedle);
    rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(260);
    rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
    rotateTransition.setAxis(new Point3D(0,0,10));
    if (rotateTransition.getStatus() != Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
      rotateTransition.stop();
    } else {
      rotateTransition.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code that currently does the rotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RotateTransition around a pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652149/rotatetransition-around-a-pivot)

Comment: But i am using an imageview so that couldn't able to take startX or Y properties

Comment: The pivot is in the coordinate space of the node itself, so the top left is represented by `(0,0)`. At most you would need to use the width and the height, which you can get from `getBoundsInLocal()`. (Shapes, such as `Line`, behave differently, in that their coordinate space prior to transformations is the coordinate space of their parent, and their specific coordinate properties, such as `startX`, `startY` etc., position them within that coordinate space.)

Comment: BTW: What's the `if` construct supposed to do? What do you expect the status of the animation to be just after creating it?